Scaling Out-of-Sample Forecasts in a Model with Normalized Variables: Reverting to Original Scale
I'm working on making forecasts using a model where variables were scaled by
$$ 
\tilde x_i = \frac{{x_i - \text{mean}(x_i)}}{{\text{sd}(x_i)}} ,
$$
and I've saved the mean and standard deviation. Now, for out-of-sample forecasts, let's say for the target variable $ ( x_i )$, based on the scaled model, how do I scale the forecasts back? With $x_i$ also containing the target variable.
Should I use the in-sample $ \text{mean}(x_i) $ and $ \text{sd}(x_i) $ to scale the out-of-sample forecasts for $(\tilde x_i)$ back, so that:
$$
\text{Re-scaled out-of-sample forecast} = \text{Scaled forecast} \times \text{sd}(x_i) + \text{mean}(x_i)
$$
What's the appropriate procedure here?

With 'variables were scaled' you mean that the target which your model tries to predict was scaled before training?

@picky_porpoise yes

If your model was trained on the scaled target observations $\tilde x_i$, then it will produce out-of-sample forecasts for the scaled target. Thus you can get forecasts for the un-scaled target $x_i$ by applying the inverse of your scaling transformation. As you have suggested, if a forecast for the scaled target is $\tilde z$, then
$$
z =  \tilde z \, \text{sd}(x_i) + \text{mean}(x_i)
$$
is the forecast for the un-scaled target.
Importantly, you should use the $\text{sd}(x_i)$ and $ \text{mean}(x_i)$ values calculated in training for a sound evaluation. Otherwise, you may use information during the evaluation which would not be there in a 'real' application of your forecasting model.

Thanks for the response. Could you please explain what you mean with a sound evaluation?

@george1994 A good evaluation should show how the model would perform in your use case.  So the evaluation setting should mimic as close as possible the way the model will be used in practice. And there you will most likely have only the mean and sd from the training set/period to work with.

so do you mean the performance for the testing sample?

@george1994 I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

with this: So the evaluation setting should mimic as close as possible the way the model will be used in practice. Do you mean to evaluate the model based on a training sample?

@george1994 No, you should evaluate on some test set. But the mean and sd should come from the training set. You can see them as two additional parameters of your model. After training they should remain fixed.

understood, thank you.
